# Entity Framework DataBase Initializors Add Columns

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

Are there any implemenations for DataBase Initializeers in EntityFramework, which adds at least new columns if missing ?

Sounds like a real common scenario to me so i don't want to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the scenario where you already have the database and you want update it from your modified model definition (code-first with data annotations or fluent mapping) than the answer is no. There are no initializers which would be able to modify existing database and there will not most probably be any in the future.

ADO.NET decided to use another approach for database upgrade which is called migrations. [First public CTP of Migrations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/07/27/code-first-migrations-walkthrough-of-august-2011-ctp.aspx) is already available.